# rstudio knitr not running pdfcrop

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to knit the mwe below to pdf using rstudio (1.2.5019)

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Me"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
    fig_crop: yes
---
This should be cropped
```{r}
library(knitr)
```



```{r named-chunk}
plot(x <- 0:100, dbinom(x, size=100, prob=0.6), type='l',
     main="Not cropped", xlab="Looks good", ylab="Nok")
```
````

The output pdf looks fine except the plot has not been cropped with pdfcrop.

Here's the log output.

> processing file: cropping.Rmd   |..................
>   |  25%   ordinary text without R code
>
> |...................................
>   |  50% label: unnamed-chunk-1
>   |....................................................
>   |  75%   ordinary text without R code
>
> |......................................................................|
>   100% label: named-chunk
>
> output file: cropping.knit.md
>
> "C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   cropping.utf8.md --to latex --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output
>   cropping.tex --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine
>   pdflatex --variable graphics --lua-filter
>   "C:/Users/marti/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua"
>   --lua-filter "C:/Users/marti/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua"
>   --variable "geometry:margin=1in"
>
> Output created: cropping.pdf

pdfcrop works just fine from my command line but isn't called by rstudio. It is also located by rstudio.

> Sys.which('pdfcrop')
>                                        pdfcrop 
>   "C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32\pdfcrop.exe"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually solved it.

````
``` {r crop-hook,cache=FALSE}
    knit_hooks$set(crop=hook_pdfcrop)
```


```{r named-chunk, crop=TRUE}
plot(x <- 0:100, dbinom(x, size=100, prob=0.6), type='l',
     main="Not cropped", xlab="Looks good", ylab="Nok")
```
````

As far as I understood from the documentation this shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: Where in the docs did you read this? [bookdown.org](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/crop-plot.html) agrees with your solution - where did you read about the syntax you used in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Install `pdfcrop` via `livetex` or `miktex` --- the one you are using to write latex documents.